# Live Reload work with Magento 2 Live Server

Tags: magento2, livereload

Today i am tried to use live reload on live server.

Almost working but when socket call, it showing error

**Provisional headers are shown**

Request URL:wss://domain_url:35729/livereload

is any body did that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally live reload with server.

you need to do port forward from localhost to your server

ssh -L 35729:127.0.0.1:35729 server_username@host

where 35729 :port number of localhost reload

make sure grunt watch is working on live server